# How can peer block validation be independent and deterministic?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Reading the Fabric ordering service documentation on [peer validation and commit](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/orderer/ordering_service.html#phase-three-validation-and-commit) it's stated that "Each peer will validate distributed blocks independently, but in a deterministic fashion, ensuring that ledgers remain consistent."

My question is, how can block validation be simultaneously independent and deterministic? It seems circular that because validation is deterministic the ledger is consistent, how can we be absolutely certain that each peer ledger is up-to-date at the time of validation?

Answer (score 2):

*"Each peer will validate distributed blocks independently..."*

This means that the peers don't depend of each other to validate the new block, so a peer can commit the block and have a state ahead of others.

*"...but in a deterministic fashion..."*

Even the time of commit of each peer is different the result is deterministic(the same result) for all the peers

**how can block validation be simultaneously independent and deterministic?**

As said earlier, the validation on commit time don't need to happen simultaneously for all peer, Fabric ensure determinism of the content of transaction by checking the signatures of Endorsers and order of transaction by checking the Orderer signature.

The peers still need to fallow the block order since it's a blockchain :)

If its still not clear comment this question and I will edit to fulfill your doubt.